# How to run a .exe with dll in different location

Tags: dll

I am working in C# and implementing Plugin Management feature to our application.  I look through dll and exe to load up plugins that are in a specific folder say Plugins.  These plugin applications have their own folder when they are installed and I will copy over the plugin application exe/dll to the Plugins folder.  However, there are some plugin applications that requires other dlls to run, but I want to minimize the duplication.  Is there a way that I can just copy over the .exe to the Plugins folder and have the other dependent dll files locate in other folder?  How would I load the the plugin in c# if the .exe and .dll is not in the same location?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://mef.codeplex.com/Wikipage